# Maximize vim's quickfix window?

Tags: python, vim

I am programming in vim and python, and use [tpope's vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) to run the current file via

```
:Dispatch python main.py
```

The printed output from the program  is directed into the **quickfix** window. Unfortunately, only the first couple of lines are visible. 
To see all of the output, I must resize the quickfix window *manually*.

My laborious workaround so far, after moving the cursor to the quickfix window, is `<C-W><C-o>`, which makes the quickfix window the only window visible.
I then go back to my source via `<C-o>`.

Is there a way to toggle a specific size of the quickfix window?
Alternatively: What would be a better way to navigate to the quickfix window, maximize it, and then go back to the last position in the source?

Comment: How do you feel about not using the quickfix window? Maybe by using a some nicer mappings like [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) to navigate the list instead? Before you dismiss this suggestion out of hand, I rarely use the quickfix window. Pretty much use it when there is more noise to signal.

Comment: Hi @PeterRincker, I am by no means bound to the quickfix window, but I would like to have more space to look at the output of the program. Maybe already a simple ``tail -f output.log'' in another terminal session would instead be helpful... Btw, installed vim-unimpaired only today in the morning :)

Answer (score 3):

The `:copen` command supports an optional `[height]` argument:

> ```
> :cope[n] [height] Open a window to show the current list of errors.
>
>                   When [height] is given, the window becomes that high
>                   (if there is room).  When [height] is omitted the
>                   window is made ten lines high.
> ```

If quickfix is opened by the plugin (and you cannot configure this), you could work around this via an `:autocmd` (as the quickfix window can be detected by its `qf` filetype):

```
:autocmd FileType qf wincmd _
```

Comment: Hi @Ingo Karkat, this is an interesting approach. The problem after ":autocmd FileType qf wincmd _" is, that the cursor is not in the quickfix window, but in the previous window. Any help on than? With the cursor in the quickfix window, the latter can be closed conveniently.

Comment: Really? That must come from the plugin; usually `:copen` takes you to the quickfix window.